# How to generate a GCS pre-signed URL without exposing the service account in the URL in Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

We don't want to expose our users to internal information like the service account name used to sign the URL. The documentation hints that using a simple service account ID is possible (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#considerations) however I could not find a way to configure this when implementing the signing
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-java

Do you know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't the option in the [library](https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage/blob/95ecae733881d5f315154fa3045164b0d295623c/google-cloud-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/StorageImpl.java#L722). Your solution is to [implement the signature by yourselves](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually), or to propose a pull request on the client library